# Strange behavior change in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, fastcgi

In a `.htaccess` context, I have a simple rewriting rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]+)/(.*) action/do.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

`dir` and `action` are in the same directory, which is also my `DocumentRoot`.

When accessing http://example.org/dir/a/b the request should (and was) rewritten to http://example.org/action/do.php?a=a&b=b without redirection or anything visible.

However since I upgraded from Apache 1.3 + mod_php to Apache 2.2 (mpm_worker) + PHP FastCGI (don't know how it's related, but it seems to be), the precedent rule returns a 404 error :

> The requested URL /var/www/action/do.php was not found on this server.

The `DocumentRoot` is now inserted in the request ! The file `/var/www/var/www/action/do.php` obviously doesn't exist.

As a workaround, I changed the rule : (added a `/` at the beginning of the second part)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]+)/(.*) /action/do.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And it works (because fortunately in this case, I'm in the `DocumentRoot` directory).

Do you know what caused this behavior change ? Did you notice the same thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what happened.

Actually, I was not in my `DocumentRoot` but in a `VirtualDocumentRoot` thanks to `mod_vhost_alias`.

The issue does not happen when using "real" virtual hosts.